# Can I change measure of the font is used for the content height?

Tags: css, html

Can I can change in CSS3 measure of the font is used for the content height example: from EM BOX to maximum ascender and descender of the font.

CSS 2.1 spec.(10.6.1 Inline, non-replaced elements) say "level 3 of CSS will probably include a property to select which measure of the font is used for the content height".
It is posible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get your point .

If your question is that if you could change font size in html, then yes you could do it .

Make a  js function which gets values from the slider and then changes the font size of the particular element accordingly.

Comment: The content area(on inline elements like span) can be the box described by the em boxes of every character in the element, strung together; or it can be the box described by the character glyphs in the element.So, is it possible for the content area to be maximum ascender and descender of the font instead of em box?